Using multiple SVGs in a webpage causing frame drops and affects the page's overall scroll experience
I'm developing a static site using NextJS, where the homepage contains multiple SVG backgrounds. The SVG has multiple paths and filters applied to it, it's causing frame drops & jittery scroll experience. I've tested without the SVGs, it seems to be working fine.
I've tried applying these CSS properties to the elements transform: translateZ(0);will-change: transform to enable GPU acceleration but it doesn't have an effect.
I've also added a Service Worker to cache the images to reduce load time, but the frame drop is still happening.
Any Insights to resolve this and improve the page's performance?
Thanks in Advance

simplify or remove the filters

How big are the svg file sizes?

The SVG files are around 5kb - 25kb

Can you show the implemented code ?
